# Android add unit test coverage into sonar

Tags: android, unit-testing, sonarqube, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have Android project that is analyzed by Sonar. I see all issues but no coverage by unit tests. I tried a lot of things but still cannot get it working. When i call 'gradlew createDebugCoverageReport' it will make directory at build/reports/coverage/debug that contains lot of files like report.xml and index.html that contains test coverage data. But in Sonar under Coverage i get message like 'This component does not have coverage details'. How can i get it working?

Sequence of commands:

```
gradlew clean assemble
gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
gradlew sonarRunner
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cz.meteocar.unit"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
                testCoverageEnabled = true
            }


        }
    }


apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

sonarRunner {
      sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000" // Address of Sonar         server
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java" // Sources
        property "sonar.projectName", "Meteocar" // Name of your project
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0.2" // Version of your project
        property "sonar.projectDescription", "Sonar" // Description of your project
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/reports/coverage/"
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/mbassador-1.2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20140107'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Jacoco` for coverage results. It works well with `sonar`:

1.Install `Android` plugin on `SonarQube`

2.Add `jacoco plugin` and create a `gradle task` on `Gradle` to generate `coverage` files, smth like:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    version "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/yourapppackagename',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*'])
    sourceDirectories = files('src/main/java')
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')
    doFirst {
        files('build/intermediates/classes/debug').getFiles().each { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3.Create `sonar.properties` file on your root directory and **include** coverage files path:

```
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=sdk/build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec
sonar.junit.reportsPath=sdk/build/test-results/debug
```

4.Run `jacoco gradle task`:

```
 ./gradlew clean assembleDebug jacocoTestReport
```

5.Run `sonar analyses`

Comment: How can i expand this solution so it works on Instrumentation tests too (AndroidJUnit4)? For best if it is all in one report?

Comment: Well what do u actually want to make it work? If its about passed or failed tests sonar supports them too and there is documentation on sonarqube official page on how to integrate it. Its easier than adding coverage report, you just have to define paths of test codes

Comment: I want to see unite test and integration test coverage on sonar plus some Overall coverage. Overall coverage will be computed by it self from unit tests and integration tests. Coverage for unit tests i already have. Now my problem is, that i have report from instrumentation tests (integration test for me) in html format and i need to convert it into Jacoco report so i can added into sonar.

Comment: This is another question and should be opened separately on `SO`. You have to explain in details your question and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tanks for help. I found out my problem was in Build tool version. After changing it into 23.0.3 everything is working well.